# Why do I have a undeclared variable existed?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc, declaration

I am writing a function in C. What I found is that when I debug in gdb, I found a pointer "result" has the same address with another pointer before "result" was declared. Part of my code:

```
char* stringSum(char* x, char* y){
    puts(x);
    puts(y);
    printf("\n");

    int lengthx=strlen(x);
    int lengthy=strlen(y);

    int lengths=MIN(lengthx,lengthy);
    int lengthl=MAX(lengthx,lengthy);

    char* s=((lengthx<=lengthy)?x:y);
    char* l=((lengthx>lengthy)?x:y);

    int returnSize=MAX(lengthx, lengthy)+2;//-----I could print result now

    printf("before, short is                          : ");puts(s);

    char* result=malloc(sizeof(char)*returnSize);//-----but result is allocated now

    printf("after allocate memory for result, short is: ");puts(s);//---s is changed!
    result[returnSize-1]='\0';
    ......
}
```

This function get the sum of two numbers (in string) so that I could calculate the sum of two large numbers. In gdb: I got this weird problem:

[My problems are in red and yellow rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KrIr.png)

(When debug in gdb) Before `char* result=malloc(sizeof(char)*returnSize);` I print s and result (so now it haven't been declared yet) and got

```
(gdb) print s
$5 = 0x61f950 "6597242170048699800240000000000"
(gdb) print result
$6 = 0x61f950 "6597242170048699800240000000000"
```

I couldn't understand that since how could an undeclared pointer points to an existing address? (This function is called by another function with a very large number of x and y (in string). If I changed them to relatively small values I will always get the right answer. What's more, if I create a new .c file and only have this function and main function, I will not have that problem anymore even with a large value.)

My second problem is that I have printed s twice and I found the second time I print (after declare the pointer result) s is changed! (Similar to the first problem, if I choose smaller values for x and y or create a new .c file, I will not have the same problem.)

I guess I have some problem with `malloc` but after search online I haven't find any useful resources will could help me solve the problem. Do I have the problem about memory management?

Comment: How is that code compiled? Did you have a look at the machine/assembly code? What is the problem with the code?

Comment: When you try to get the value of `result` before it is defined, I believe the outcome, surprisingly, is undefined ;). In this case, it turns out to be the same as `s`

Comment: But the problem appears to be that the opposite is also true somehow, that `s` is magically changed when `result` is assigned...

Comment: Are you complaining about `gdb` being able to print a variable before the execution has reached its declaration? It's normal. `gdb` doesn't know about the point where the variable was declared. The value printed by `gdb` in this situation will be unpredictable.

Comment: @Jerfov2 Thanks a lot. Do you mean that this could happen some time? It seems something happens out of my control and I believe there should be some way to solve it. And what do you mean by "outcome"? Did I forget to do something?

Comment: As for changing the result of `s`, this normally shouldn't happen and may be caused by a bug elsewhere. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m. I've never know that! Then I guess my only problem is the second one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Olaf with gcc. My problem is that I do not understand why the string pointed by s is changed after `char* result=malloc(sizeof(char)*returnSize);` The outputs of s with `puts(s)` was showed in yellow rectangle.

Comment: @Gloria `puts` prints the underlying string pointed to by `s`. So the value of `s` itself shouldn't change, but the string being pointed to by `s` (and also `x` or `y`) might change

Comment: @Jerfov2 That seems reasonable. But is there some possible way to  change the value pointed by that pointer? I mean, I just allocated some space for another one...

Comment: One question before I answer yours. Are the values of `x` and `y` arbitrary. (i.e. do they point to something that you know doesn't change?)

Comment: http://ideone.com/NPu1rZ Here `s` doesn't change, which is expected. If you see `s` changing, we would have no way of knowing why or helping you to find out without seeing an entire program that exhibits this behaviour.

Comment: @Jerfov2 This function was called by another function for many times. And every time it was called, of course x and y have different value. In this function, the value of x and y shouldn't be changed. Hope that's what you are asking.

Comment: @Gloria If the char array pointed to by `s`, `x`, or `y` changes, then `puts`'s output will be different. Try using `printf("%p\n", s)` instead of `puts` and tell us what the output is

Comment: @n.m.Thank you! Yes. I have also tried what you've done and got the right answer. [This](http://ideone.com/sqUsSi) is my code which I am trying to get the product of two numbers in string with karatsuba method, if you want to check with that. My problem was in line 117-119. If I tried with strings with less digits the answer was right so I guess I have problem with maybe memory...

Comment: @Jerfov2 I got the same output address for printf. (Just as n.m 's guess, I will not have that problem if I call this function directly in main. So now I guess maybe there are something wrong in other part of my code that I didn't post.)

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the code as a part of the question, not as a link and not in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two serious problems with your code.

The first problem is that you never `free` what you `malloc`, creating sizeable memory leaks at each recursive call.

The second problem is that you are trying to assign strings, which doesn't have the effect you hope for.

Here is an example of what you do (comments mine):

```
 // allocate some memory and assign its address to abcd
 char* abcd=malloc(sizeof(char)*returnSize);

 // throw it away by assigning a different value to abcd
 abcd=karatsuba(stringSum(a,b),stringSum(c,d));
 // then assign yet another different value to abcd
 abcd=stringSubstract(abcd,ac);
 // and another one
 abcd=stringSubstract(abcd,bd);//ab+cd   

 // Code below overflows, because memory abcd is pointing to is 
 // not the original block allocated for it (you threw it away).
 // It is a block allocated and returned by stringSubstract.
 // Its length is not necessarily sufficient to accommodate all
 // the data you are trying to stuff in it.
 int labcd=strlen(abcd);     
 for(i=0;i<=(ns/2-1);i++){
     abcd[labcd+i]='0';
 }
 abcd[lac+i]='\0';
```

You can verify that this is the case by running your program under `valgrind`. You will get error messages that indicate a buffer overflow just before the mysterious shortening of `s`. It all goes downhill from there.

In order to fix the problem, you may want to use `strcpy` instead of pointer assignment. Another way to fix it would be ditching the `abcd = malloc(...)` lines in the beginning of the function, and using `realloc` to make sure they have the allocations have enough size.

In addition you definitely want to fix the memory leaks. You need to call `free` for each variable you `malloc` after you're done with it. If you are returning a `malloc`ed variable, the caller needs to free it after using it.

Comment: @ Thanks so much! I use `strcpy` now and the string pointed by `s` will not be modified anymore. My problem for this question seems to be solved and I know there are some other problems in my code. Thanks for your suggestion about `valgrind` because I've never tried that before. I do found a lot errors under valgrind.